# How do i get data from flask to my template using ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have some data in flask that I need to fetch and use in my template but the fetching should be done asynchronously using ajax and every 15 milliseconds.

Most of the solutions I have found are the other way around like from template to flask through ajax but I need the opposite.

```
@application.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
  data = (some data i want to fetch every 15ms on test.html)
  return render_template('test.html', data=data)
```

Comment: Please explain the rather short interval of 15 ms.

Comment: Do you need to redraw the whole page?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i need to plot a live graph but a new value is going to keep coming from flask that i will use on my template and add it to plotly plot by extend trace method the problem is how do i keep fetching that new value every 15 ms from flask to template using ajax without reloading the page

Comment: Check `setInterval`. But like Klaus says, 15ms is a bit short and will likely make your users hate you. Have you considered that with these requirements maybe a web app is not the best solution?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes i know setinterval my doubt is how do i fetch data from flask using jquery's $.ajax and use it, i haven't used much ajax before consider me a newbie

Comment: Then you'll have to give us something more. I mean, what's the actual problem? What's stopping you from calling `$.ajax('/test', settings)` and handling the result?

Answer (score 1):

An asynchronous (or Ajax) request is similar to the routes and view functions that using templates, with the only difference that instead of returning HTML or a redirect, it just returns data, formatted as XML or more commonly JSON. Below you can see the example where returns the user info in JSON format:

On the server:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/ajax_example/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    return jsonify(user)
```

On the client:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax('{{ url_for('main.get_user') }}).done(
                function(get_user_info) {
                    *blahblahblah*
                    }
            );
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how do i render the template for the first time

Comment: @PraharshMishra you need two routes - 1 for render page, 2 for get data in json format